# In Android, one activity can have how many threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm new to Android, I know how to create an Activity and a thread.
My question is how many threads can be held in one Activity?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is how many threads can be held in one Activity?

"Can" be held? Your practical limit will be heap space. Depending on your chosen stack size for the threads, there could be thousands.

However, having that many threads would be rather bizarre. A typical sizing algorithm for a *program* is two times the number of cores plus one (2*N+1, where N is the number of cores).

Comment: Good answer, might be worth mentioning that threads are not cheap to create and often you will be served just as well by posting messages on a thread with a message queue or using an AsyncTask.